# RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am writing a test for my Flask app that uses Flask-SQLAlchemy. In `models.py`, I used `db = SQLAlchemy()`, and wrote a function to configure it with the app. But when I run my test, I get the error "RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app". I'm not sure where the test file is creating a new instance of SQLAlchemy.

```py
# flaskr.py
from flask import Flask
from models import setup_db

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    setup_db(app)
    return app
```

```py
# models.py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

database_path = "postgresql://student:student@localhost/bookshelf"

db = SQLAlchemy()

def setup_db(app, database_path=database_path):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_path
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

```
# test_flaskr.py
import unittest

from flaskr import create_app
from models import setup_db

class BookTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        setup_db(self.app, "postgresql://student:student@localhost/bookshelf_test")

        with self.app.app_context():
            self.db = SQLAlchemy()
            self.db.init_app(self.app)
            self.db.create_all()

    def test_get_paginated_books(self):
        res = self.client.get("/books")
        data = res.json
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue(data["success"])
        self.assertTrue(data["total_books"])
        self.assertTrue(len(data["books"]))
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
$ python -m unittest -v test_flaskr.py

test_get_paginated_books (test_flaskr.BookTestCase) ... ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_paginated_books (test_flaskr.BookTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):      
  File "C:\Users\swilk\OneDrive\DOCS-Programming\udacity-demo-bookshelf\backend\test_flaskr.py", line 21, in setUp      
    setup_db(self.app, self.database_path)
  File "C:\Users\swilk\OneDrive\DOCS-Programming\udacity-demo-bookshelf\backend\models.py", line 24, in setup_db        
    db.init_app(app)
  File "C:\Users\swilk\OneDrive\DOCS-Programming\udacity-demo-bookshelf\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 253, in init_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 tests in 0.226s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-SQLAlchemy 3 raises an error for a common incorrect setup of the extension. You must only call `db.init_app(app)` once for a given pair of `db` and `app` instances.

You defined `db = SQLAlchemy()` in `models`, then called `init_app` on it in `create_app`. You must use that `db`, not create another instance. You must not call `db.init_app` again, it was already called in `create_app`.

Your test's `setUp` is calling `create_app`, but then it's also calling `setup_db` again even though that's already called as part of `create_app`. Then further down, you're creating a new `self.db = SQLAlchemy()` and calling `init_app` on it with the same app you've already set up the other instance on. This is all incorrect.

It looks like you're doing this because you're trying to set a database configuration for the test. As explained in [the Flask tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/tutorial/factory/#the-application-factory), that's what the `create_app` function's `test_config` parameter is for. Get rid of the `setup_db` function, it's unnecessary indirection. Pass your test configuration to the factory to override default config.

```py
def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI="postgresql://student:student@localhost/bookshelf"
    )
    
    if test_config is not None:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

    return app
```

```py
from flaskr import create_app, db

class BookTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app({
            "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI": "postgresql://student:student@localhost/bookshelf_test"
        })
```

Note that nothing was done directly with `db` in `setUp`, it was only imported to be used during tests.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I was able to get things working the way davidism recommended, so I am leaving that as the correct/accepted answer.

But, was running into some issues with other areas of the demo/tutorial the code was originally from, so I tried to rebuild the code, keeping all three original functions (**create_app()**, **setup_db()**, and **setUp(self)**).

Basically, what I did was to add the URI for the database as an optional argument for the **create_app()** function and set a conditional to run **setup_db()** on the default/test database depending on whether the optional URI argument was included when calling **create_app()**.

```
from models import Book, setup_db

def create_app(db_URI="", test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)  
    if db_URI:
        setup_db(app,db_URI)
    else:
        setup_db(app)
```

No changes were made to the **setup_db()** function in models.py.

```
database_path = "postgresql://student:student@localhost/bookshelf"

db = SQLAlchemy()

def setup_db(app, database_path=database_path):
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_path

    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

In test_flaskr.py, I made some changes to the structure so we assign the variable for database_path before calling **create_app()**, and we can therefore use database_path as the optional URI argument. I also commented out the **setup_db()** method from this file, as well as the block under the line 'with self.app.app_context(), since these were just causing problems.

```
import unittest
from flaskr import create_app
from models import Book, setup_db

class BookTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        """Define test variables and initialize app."""
        
        self.database_path = "postgresql://student:student@localhost/bookshelf_test"

        self.app = create_app(self.database_path)
        self.client = self.app.test_client
        
        #setup_db(self.app, self.database_path)

        #with self.app.app_context():
        #    self.db = SQLAlchemy()
        #    self.db.init_app(self.app)
        #    self.db.create_all()

    def test_get_paginated_books(self):
        res = self.client.get("/books")
        data = res.json

        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue(data["success"])
        self.assertTrue(data["total_books"])
        self.assertTrue(len(data["books"]))
```