# How to test Flask with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

Maybe its a primitive question and I miss something very obvious but I can't figure it out quickly. I created a basic Flask app and want to add testing functionality to it. I want to test the function that tests populating databases, but all the examples Ive found on using pytest or unittest affect the actual database. Is it possible to unbind Flask app from an existing database and add a new one at the setUp function and then remove it in tearDown? Patching also seems to work only for returning objects and not for accepting data. Or it is just not the way the app`s interaction with a database is tested?

I tried to use flask_testing, pytest, unittest and @pytest.fixtures.
I tried to use flask_testing, pytest, unittest and @pytest.fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to this problem is to set an environment variable with database URL. You can pass a different URL depending on whether you are running the app in test or production.

On command line:

```
$ export DATABASE_URL="my-database-url"
```

In the application:

```
# import the os library
import os

# use the environment variable in the method that connects to database
...
connect_to_database(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
...
```

Now you can set the environment variable before running tests, and the application will point to database of your choice.

Comment: I either get `untimeError: A 'SQLAlchemy' instance has already been registered on this Flask app. Import and use that instance instead.` error or tests manipulate an actual database, how to do It properly?

Comment: You can set the database you want to point to conditionally `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`. The message you are getting seems to indicate you are trying to something like `db.init_app(app)` twice. See this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75523569/runtimeerror-a-sqlalchemy-instance-has-already-been-registered-on-this-flask